# Does RGB supports decimal values?

Tags: android, colors, rgb

If I enter a RGB values like `194.5,193.5, 192.5`, the result color is the same as the values `194, 193, 192`. Is there any option that color will be changed as light or thick based on the decimal values too?

Comment: No. Niet. Nein. Nada. No decimals are allowed in byte values.

Answer (score 6):

RGB values are composed of three 8-bit integers (`byte`), one each for red, blue and green with value from 0 to 255. There is also a fourth 8-bit integer that is used for opacity. This also has values from 0 to 255. This is also referred to as the "alpha value". There are no fractional parts.

Answer (score 0):

No, RGB supports 256 values for each color and that is it. If you want to change the color further, consider using ARGB, where the first value will affect the alpha value of the color, resulting in it being thicker or lighter, as well as transparent.